# Font awesome icon works in one td only after using it from Javascript

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I'm trying to use font-awesome icons in a table according to the content in the span tag. If the content in the span tag contains "listed" then it will have one type of icon; if it has "not_listed" then another.

I have hard-coded the span tag contents because I am going to get those from an API. API always responds with listed or not_listed. This is another reason why I can't use icon tags inside HTML so I'm sending it through Javascript.

The first span tag changes the content to an icon but the rest doesn't. Please check below the code I have tried.

```js
var blStatus = document.querySelector(".bl-status");
if (blStatus === "listed") {
  blStatus.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>';
} else {
  blStatus.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Guava</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Grape</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Mango</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Read the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector: The Document method querySelector() **returns the first** Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

Comment: Adding to j08691, `blStatus === "listed"` should be `blStatus.innerText === "listed"` and that should be within a loop

Comment: Use this code `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".bl-status")).forEach(x => {
  if (x.innerText === "listed") {
    x.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>';
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>';
  }
});`

Comment: Hey it works perfectly now. But can you please tell me why you used Array.from()?

Comment: @SagarV Post your work as an answer

Comment: @Zak because `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList not an array. Most of the modern browsers support `forEach` in nodelist but some doesn't (if I remember it correctly)

Comment: @SagarV sure but your answer is valid and on point. Get the points for it. ;)

Comment: Thanks mate. Can any one of you please upvote if you think this question is helpful?  :(

Comment: Thanks guys. God bless you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelector` returns the first matching element only. So you need to use `querySelectorAll`.

Also you need to replace `blStatus === "listed"` to `blStatus.innerText === "listed"`

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".bl-status")).forEach(blStatus => {
  if (blStatus.innerText === "listed") {
    blStatus.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>';
  } else {
    blStatus.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>';
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Guava</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Grape</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Mango</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Based on your comment

> <sub>Hi Sagar, hope you're doing well. I needed another help if that's not a problem for you. The JS code you helped me with, can it be modified a little so that it also says how many are listed and how many are not listed? I tried bl-status.innerText.length in the if statement but it just returns one item. Thanks in advance. – Zak 2 hours ago</sub>

Here's the edited snippet.

```js
let count = {"listed" : 0, "unlisted": 0};
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".bl-status")).forEach(blStatus => {
  if (blStatus.innerText === "listed") {
    count.listed += 1;
    blStatus.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>';
  } else {
    count.unlisted += 1;
    blStatus.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>';
  }
});
console.log(count);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Guava</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Grape</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">not_listed</span> Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="bl-status">listed</span> Mango</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, hope you're doing well. I needed another help if that's not a problem for you. The JS code you helped me with, can it be modified a little so that it also says how many are listed and how many are not listed? I tried bl-status.innerText.length in the if statement but it just returns one item. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey man. it's perfect. Just as I wanted. Wish I could code like you.